# Custom tooltip validation error WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a custom tooltip. The problem is that I can not display the error text. This code works perfectly (a simple tooltip)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Polygon Fill="Red"
                         Margin="0,2,2,0"
                         Points="10,10 10,0 0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}">
                </Polygon>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

But this code, not work, not show the error

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Polygon Fill="Red"
                         Margin="0,2,2,0"
                         Points="10,10 10,0 0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Polygon.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Content="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Background="Red" />
                    </Polygon.ToolTip>
                </Polygon>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tooltip itself and the AdornedElementPlaceholder reside in different namescopes so binding using an ElementName won't work.

But you can set the Tag property of the Polygon to the ErrorContent and bind the Content property of the Tooltip to the Tag property of its PlacementTarget (which is the Polygon). This works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Polygon Fill="Red"
                         Margin="0,2,2,0"
                         Points="10,10 10,0 0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                         Tag="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}">
                        <Polygon.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Background="Red" />
                        </Polygon.ToolTip>
                    </Polygon>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `(Validation.Errors)[0]` will be troublesome as you are referencing a particular object from a list that will update and change therefore breaking the binding.

The first example where you use `(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.` is more suitable as it matches your first implementation which works.

I ran into issues with this a few years back, basically never use an index in a binding unless you are absolutely 100% sure it will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried that too but it did not work.

Comment: ahh it may be to do with the tooltip object being inserted rather than text given to its own tooltip property.

If i were you i would change it back to the first example and use a style to manipulate those attributes. that way you avoid the object reference hassle.

I have done this before in my applications as it is good practice to have style separated. It also lets you swap dynamically if you wish which can look super cool.